# After piping Incoming mails to external script, mails are not shown in Inbox in iRedmail

Tags: postfix, dovecot, pipe, iredmail

I have been trying to pipe incoming mails to my python script which is just trying to read a mail and look for keywords and call api. But for some reasons my mails are not being delivered to my inbox. I am new to postfix and this is my first time using iRedMail.

This is the mail log

```
Aug 5 06:21:45 mail postfix/postscreen[675880]: CONNECT from [209.85.128.173]:34774 to [144.126.209.67]:25
Aug 5 06:21:51 mail postfix/postscreen[675880]: PASS NEW [209.85.128.173]:34774
Aug 5 06:21:51 mail postfix/smtpd[675884]: connect from mail-yw1-f173.google.com[209.85.128.173]
Aug 5 06:21:52 mail postfix/smtpd[675884]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-yw1-f173.google.com[209.85.128.173]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
Aug 5 06:21:52 mail postfix/smtpd[675884]: 4Lzb8w1yJ7z3wJt: client=mail-yw1-f173.google.com[209.85.128.173]
Aug 5 06:21:52 mail postfix/cleanup[675887]: 4Lzb8w1yJ7z3wJt: message-id=<CAB57bmv5gYvbOdMPhupRx1mPUE3tr-TrzmPo5gse_aHt4=GkWQ@mail.gmail.com>
Aug 5 06:21:52 mail postfix/qmgr[499162]: 4Lzb8w1yJ7z3wJt: from=<adamariempire@gmail.com>, size=2592, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[675891]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[675891]: 4Lzb905gxJz3wKV: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/cleanup[675887]: 4Lzb905gxJz3wKV: message-id=<CAB57bmv5gYvbOdMPhupRx1mPUE3tr-TrzmPo5gse_aHt4=GkWQ@mail.gmail.com>
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[675891]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/qmgr[499162]: 4Lzb905gxJz3wKV: from=<adamariempire@gmail.com>, size=3141, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail amavis[634547]: (634547-07) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [209.85.128.173]:34774 [209.85.128.173] ESMTP/ESMTP <adamariempire@gmail.com> -> <adamari.net@payee.io>, (ESMTPS://[209.85.128.173]:34774), Queue-ID: 4Lzb8w1yJ7z3wJt, Message-ID: <CAB57bmv5gYvbOdMPhupRx1mPUE3tr-TrzmPo5gse_aHt4=GkWQ@mail.gmail.com>, mail_id: dBfdCmq0E1Rh, b: qPXMagzZ6, Hits: -0.199, size: 2592, queued_as: 4Lzb905gxJz3wKV, Subject: "Test 11", From: <adamariempire@gmail.com> (dkim:AUTHOR), helo=mail-yw1-f173.google.com, Tests: [DKIM_SIGNED=0.1,DKIM_VALID=-0.1,DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1,DKIM_VALID_EF=-0.1,FREEMAIL_FROM=0.001,HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE=-0.0001,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2=-0.001,SPF_HELO_NONE=0.001,SPF_PASS=-0.001], autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no, autolearnscore=-0.198, dkim_i=@gmail.com, dkim_sd=20210112:gmail.com, 4521 ms
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/amavis/smtp[675888]: 4Lzb8w1yJ7z3wJt: to=<adamari.net@payee.io>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=4.6, delays=0.05/0.01/0/4.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4Lzb905gxJz3wKV)
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/qmgr[499162]: 4Lzb8w1yJ7z3wJt: removed
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/pipe[675892]: 4Lzb905gxJz3wKV: to=<adamari.net@payee.io>, relay=external-pipe, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via external-pipe service)
Aug 5 06:21:56 mail postfix/qmgr[499162]: 4Lzb905gxJz3wKV: removed
```

this is main.cf

```
# --------------------
# INSTALL-TIME CONFIGURATION INFORMATION
#
# location of the Postfix queue. Default is /var/spool/postfix.
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

# location of all postXXX commands. Default is /usr/sbin.
command_directory = /usr/sbin

# location of all Postfix daemon programs (i.e. programs listed in the
# master.cf file). This directory must be owned by root.
# Default is /usr/libexec/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin

# location of Postfix-writable data files (caches, random numbers).
# This directory must be owned by the mail_owner account (see below).
# Default is /var/lib/postfix.
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

# owner of the Postfix queue and of most Postfix daemon processes.
# Specify the name of a user account THAT DOES NOT SHARE ITS USER OR GROUP ID
# WITH OTHER ACCOUNTS AND THAT OWNS NO OTHER FILES OR PROCESSES ON THE SYSTEM.
# In particular, don't specify nobody or daemon. PLEASE USE A DEDICATED USER.
# Default is postfix.
mail_owner = postfix

# The following parameters are used when installing a new Postfix version.
#
# sendmail_path: The full pathname of the Postfix sendmail command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible mail posting interface.
#
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail

# newaliases_path: The full pathname of the Postfix newaliases command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible command to build alias databases.
#
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases

# full pathname of the Postfix mailq command. This is the Sendmail-compatible
# mail queue listing command.
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq

# group for mail submission and queue management commands.
# This must be a group name with a numerical group ID that is not shared with
# other accounts, not even with the Postfix account.
setgid_group = postdrop

# external command that is executed when a Postfix daemon program is run with
# the -D option.
#
# Use "command .. & sleep 5" so that the debugger can attach before
# the process marches on. If you use an X-based debugger, be sure to
# set up your XAUTHORITY environment variable before starting Postfix.
#
debugger_command =
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

debug_peer_level = 2

# --------------------
# CUSTOM SETTINGS
#

# SMTP server response code when recipient or domain not found.
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

# Do not notify local user.
biff = no

# Disable the rewriting of "site!user" into "user@site".
swap_bangpath = no

# Disable the rewriting of the form "user%domain" to "user@domain".
allow_percent_hack = no

# Allow recipient address start with '-'.
allow_min_user = no

# Disable the SMTP VRFY command. This stops some techniques used to
# harvest email addresses.
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# Enable both IPv4 and/or IPv6: ipv4, ipv6, all.
inet_protocols = all
# Enable all network interfaces.
inet_interfaces = all

#
# TLS settings.
#
# SSL key, certificate, CA
#
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs

#
# Disable SSLv2, SSLv3
#
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

#
# Fix 'The Logjam Attack'.
#
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh512_param.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem

tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

# Log only a summary message on TLS handshake completion — no logging of client
# certificate trust-chain verification errors if client certificate
# verification is not required. With Postfix 2.8 and earlier, log the summary
# message, peer certificate summary information and unconditionally log
# trust-chain verification errors.
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

# Opportunistic TLS: announce STARTTLS support to remote SMTP clients, but do
# not require that clients use TLS encryption.
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

# Produce `Received:` message headers that include information about the
# protocol and cipher used, as well as the remote SMTP client CommonName and
# client certificate issuer CommonName.
# This is disabled by default, as the information may be modified in transit
# through other mail servers. Only information that was recorded by the final
# destination can be trusted.
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes

# Opportunistic TLS, used when Postfix sends email to remote SMTP server.
# Use TLS if this is supported by the remote SMTP server, otherwise use
# plaintext.
# References:
# - http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_may
# - http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level
smtp_tls_security_level = may

# Use the same CA file as smtpd.
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

# Enable long, non-repeating, queue IDs (queue file names).
# The benefit of non-repeating names is simpler logfile analysis and easier
# queue migration (there is no need to run "postsuper" to change queue file
# names that don't match their message file inode number).
enable_long_queue_ids = yes

# Reject unlisted sender and recipient
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes

# Header and body checks with PCRE table
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks.pcre

# A mechanism to transform commands from remote SMTP clients.
# This is a last-resort tool to work around client commands that break
# interoperability with the Postfix SMTP server. Other uses involve fault
# injection to test Postfix's handling of invalid commands.
# Requires Postfix-2.7+.
smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre

# HELO restriction
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
permit_mynetworks
permit_sasl_authenticated
check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
reject_unknown_helo_hostname

# Sender restrictions
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
reject_non_fqdn_sender
reject_unlisted_sender
permit_mynetworks
permit_sasl_authenticated
check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access.pcre
reject_unknown_sender_domain

# Recipient restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
reject_non_fqdn_recipient
reject_unlisted_recipient
check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
permit_mynetworks
permit_sasl_authenticated
reject_unauth_destination
check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:12340

# END-OF-MESSAGE restrictions
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777

# Data restrictions
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

# SRS (Sender Rewriting Scheme) support
#sender_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:7778
#sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
#recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:7779
#recipient_canonical_classes= envelope_recipient,header_recipient

proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

# Avoid duplicate recipient messages. Default is 'yes'.
enable_original_recipient = no

# Virtual support.
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail

# Do not set virtual_alias_domains.
virtual_alias_domains =

#
# Enable SASL authentication on port 25 and force TLS-encrypted SASL authentication.
# WARNING: NOT RECOMMENDED to enable smtp auth on port 25, all end users should
# be forced to submit email through port 587 instead.
#
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

# hostname
myhostname = mail.payee.io
myorigin = mail.payee.io
mydomain = mail.payee.io

# trusted SMTP clients which are allowed to relay mail through Postfix.
#
# Note: additional IP addresses/networks listed in mynetworks should be listed
# in iRedAPD setting 'MYNETWORKS' (in `/opt/iredapd/settings.py`) too.
# for example:
#
# MYNETWORKS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.0/24', ...]
#
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1 [::1]

# Accepted local emails
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases

# Default message_size_limit.
message_size_limit = 15728640

# The set of characters that can separate a user name from its extension
# (example: user+foo), or a .forward file name from its extension (example:
# .forward+foo).
# Postfix 2.11 and later supports multiple characters.
recipient_delimiter = +

# The time after which the sender receives a copy of the message headers of
# mail that is still queued. Default setting is disabled (0h) by Postfix.
#delay_warning_time = 1h

# Do not display the name of the recipient table in the "User unknown" responses.
# The extra detail makes trouble shooting easier but also reveals information
# that is nobody elses business.
show_user_unknown_table_name = no
compatibility_level = 2
#
# Lookup virtual mail accounts
#
transport_maps =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_maillist.cf
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf

sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_dependent_relayhost_maps.cf

# Lookup table with the SASL login names that own the sender (MAIL FROM) addresses.
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf

virtual_mailbox_domains =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf

relay_domains =
$mydestination
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf

virtual_mailbox_maps =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

virtual_alias_maps =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf

sender_bcc_maps =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf

recipient_bcc_maps =
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf

#
# Postscreen
#
postscreen_greet_action = drop
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2

# Attention:
# - zen.spamhaus.org free tire has 3 limits
# (https://www.spamhaus.org/organization/dnsblusage/):
#
# 1) Your use of the Spamhaus DNSBLs is non-commercial*, and
# 2) Your email traffic is less than 100,000 SMTP connections per day, and
# 3) Your DNSBL query volume is less than 300,000 queries per day.
#
# - FAQ: "Your DNSBL blocks nothing at all!"
# https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#261
#
# It's strongly recommended to use a local DNS server for cache.
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*2

postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/postscreen_dnsbl_reply
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr

# Require Postfix-2.11+
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -2

#
# Dovecot SASL support.
#
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

#
# mlmmj - mailing list manager
#
mlmmj_destination_recipient_limit = 1

#
# Amavisd + SpamAssassin + ClamAV
#
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# Concurrency per recipient limit.
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

this is master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file. For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type private unpriv chroot wakeup maxproc command + args
# (yes) (yes) (no) (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp inet n - y - 1 postscreen
smtpd pass - - y - - smtpd
dnsblog unix - - y - 0 dnsblog
tlsproxy unix - - y - 0 tlsproxy
#submission inet n - y - - smtpd
# -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
# -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
# -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
# -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
# -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
# -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
# -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
# -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
# -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
# -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps inet n - y - - smtpd
# -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
# -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
# -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
# -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
# -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
# -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
# -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
# -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
# -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628 inet n - y - - qmqpd
#smtp inet n - - - - smtpd
pickup unix n - n 60 1 pickup
-o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
cleanup unix n - n - 0 cleanup
#qmgr unix n - n 300 1 oqmgr
qmgr unix n - n 300 1 qmgr
tlsmgr unix - - n 1000? 1 tlsmgr
rewrite unix - - n - - trivial-rewrite
bounce unix - - n - 0 bounce
defer unix - - n - 0 bounce
trace unix - - n - 0 bounce
verify unix - - n - 1 verify
flush unix n - n 1000? 0 flush
proxymap unix - - n - - proxymap
proxywrite unix - - n - 1 proxymap
smtp unix - - n - - smtp
# -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
relay unix - - n - - smtp
-o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq unix n - n - - showq
error unix - - n - - error
retry unix - - n - - error
discard unix - - n - - discard
local unix - n n - - local
virtual unix - n n - - virtual
lmtp unix - - n - - lmtp
anvil unix - - n - 1 anvil
scache unix - - n - 1 scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent. See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
postlog unix-dgram n - n - 1 postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
# lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
# mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
# virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus unix - n n - - pipe
# user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix - n n - - pipe
# flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
maildrop unix - n n - - pipe flags=DRhu
user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
uucp unix - n n - - pipe flags=Fqhu
user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail unix - n n - - pipe flags=F user=ftn
argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp unix - n n - - pipe flags=Fq.
user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n n - 2 pipe flags=R
user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop}
${user} ${extension}

mailman unix - n n - - pipe flags=FR
user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop}
${user}
# Submission, port 587, force TLS connection.
submission inet n - n - - smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/submission
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
-o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026

# smtps, port 465, force SSL connection.
465 inet n - n - - smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
-o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
-o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026

# Use dovecot's `deliver` program as LDA.
dovecot unix - n n - - pipe
flags=DRh user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${domain} -m ${extension}

# mlmmj - mailing list manager
# ${nexthop} is '%d/%u' in transport ('mlmmj:%d/%u')
mlmmj unix - n n - - pipe
flags=ORhu user=mlmmj:mlmmj argv=/usr/bin/mlmmj-amime-receive -L /var/vmail/mlmmj/${nexthop}

# Amavisd integration.
smtp-amavis unix - - n - 4 smtp
-o syslog_name=postfix/amavis
-o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
-o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
-o disable_dns_lookups=yes
-o max_use=20

# smtp port used by Amavisd to re-inject scanned email back to Postfix
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - n - - smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/10025
-o content_filter=
-o mynetworks_style=host
-o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
-o local_recipient_maps=
-o relay_recipient_maps=
-o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
-o smtp_tls_security_level=none
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
-o smtpd_restriction_classes=
-o smtpd_delay_reject=no
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
-o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
-o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
-o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
-o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
-o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
-o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings

# smtp port used by mlmmj to re-inject scanned email back to Postfix, with
# address mapping support
127.0.0.1:10028 inet n - n - - smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/10028
-o content_filter=
-o mynetworks_style=host
-o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
-o local_recipient_maps=
-o relay_recipient_maps=
-o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
-o smtp_tls_security_level=none
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
-o smtpd_restriction_classes=
-o smtpd_delay_reject=no
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
-o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
-o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
-o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
-o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
-o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
-o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks

external-pipe unix - n n - - pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/home/vmail/readMail.py
```

Comment: Your logs show a message being sent to your script. What is the problem, then?

Comment: Incoming mails are not shown in inbox. Someone told me to call dovecot lda command so my script could pipe the email content back. I don't how and where to call this dovecot lda command. TBH I really don't know a single stuff about postfix and dovecot. Please help me